# Image hover effect doesn't work over text

Tags: html, css, hover

I have an image I want to display as a link.  I have a hover effect when the mouse is over the image, but I also want to overlay a text label onto the image.  The problem is, when the mouse is over the text, the image effect stops working.

My code is below.  Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

```
<html>

<style>
    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .pic {
        border: 5px solid #FF0000;  
        float: left;
        width: 475px;
        height: 375px;
        margin: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative; 

        -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #C0C0C0;
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #C0C0C0;  
    }

    .grow img {
        width: 475px;
        height: 375px;

        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
           -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
             -o-transition: all 1s ease;
            -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
                transition: all 1s ease;
    }

    .grow img:hover {
        width: 570px;
        height: 450px;
    }

    .label {
        top: 150px;
            position:absolute;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:500%; 
            color: FF0000;
            width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<a href="MyLink.html">
    <div class="grow pic">
        <img src="MyImage.jpg" alt="TITLE">
        <div class="label">TITLE</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try disabling pointer-events:

```
.label { pointer-events:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hover is just on your image, apply the hover to the div.

example:

```
.grow:hover img {
    //styles
}
```